# How can I be notified in ASP.NET when a certain update happens in my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, updates

I need to be notified of specific changes that happen in my database, e.g. when a specific value becomes null or when an integer changes to a value between a certain range. I was looking into using triggers, but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

Is there a way I can implement this using ASP.NET?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to say, if something changes on server side, you want changes to reflect on client side like push notifications?

Comment: No, not quite. I need to be able to see if an update was made to a certain value in my table. For example, I have a cash value for an item that is set to $10. If it gets changed to below $5, I somehow need to be notified.

Comment: So... couple things.  1.  Are you not in control of all the data going into your database?  You're providing direct database access to 3rd parties?  2.  What exactly does `I ... need to be notified` mean?  How would you like to be notified?    Without answers to those questions my best suggestion is to put some monkey in front of a SSMS session, have them press the refresh query button every few seconds and give you a call when the criteria is met.

Comment: To achieve this what you have tried as of now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function of SQL Server, called Query Notifications, that can be used by an app to know when some data changes. In .NET it's used through the [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) class and/or the [SqlNotificationRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqlnotificationrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like just what I'm looking for

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody You are right... I gave you a +1... But next time you should write at least some words on the name of the "technology" you are linking... Giving an opaque goo.gl link isn't very beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to keep track of these types of changes in a Database.  You could first put a trigger on the table it's self to track inserts, deletes, and updates.

You could even put a trigger on selects, but if you don't care who is looking at your data I would not.  The issue this method is that if you use a generic user name and password for your database, then it will always show that user.

The second choice is to setup some business logic that everytime one of these events happen, to track it in a table.

Please go through this http://goo.gl/ByxHq . This articles exactly shows how to reflect changes in asp.net based on update in database.